# Is there way to pass the percentage (%) to routine?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, dos, subroutine

dos-batch file

The input file has three records:

```
HOW NOW BROWN COW 

JACK AND JILL 

100% JUST YOU & ME
```

Script is as follows:

```
@echo off

set infile=e:\file.txt
set outfile=e:\outfile.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%H in (%infile%) do (
    call :Loop "%%H"
)

exit /b 0

:Loop
    for %%a in (%*) do echo %%~a >> %outfile%
exit /b 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
E:\>foo2

E:\>type outfile.txt
HOW NOW BROWN COW

JACK AND JILL

100 JUST YOU & ME
```

The character % is gone!
do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

It's a special character, if you make that 100%% it will output correctly as 100%.  I would imagine there is some way to handle that gracefully, but you may have to play around some.

**EDIT:**  Did some digging and came across  BatchSubstitute.bat on http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php

Adapted it to this and I think it should work for you - if anyone fully understands what's happening, I'd like ot hear it - I only have a vauge notion:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


set infile=e:\file.txt
set outfile=e:\outfile.txt

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %infile%|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line%%" 
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >> %outfile% 
    ) ELSE echo. >> %outfile%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is the `call :loop "%%H"`, you can't use `call` to transfer content by value, as it can change the content, here the % is removed.

Another way is to call by reference with a variable, `call :func myVar`.
But as `call` is really slow, the best way is to do the stuff right in the loop.

Another problem with for-loops are the exclamation marks `!` and carets `^`.
Normally they will be destroyed, but you can avoid this with the delayed toggling technic.

```
set infile=e:\file.txt
set outfile=e:\outfile.txt
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"findstr /n ^^ %infile%"') do (
   set "line=%%A"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   set "line=!line:*:=!"
   (echo(!line!)>>%outfile%

   rem CALL :func line
   endlocal
)
```